# How to get the form control value from a dynamically build from in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, angular-formbuilder

In here I am passing some data from parent to child component to build a dynamic form.

This is my parent component html

```
<app-child-com  *ngIf="info.length>0" #FormFieldValues [info]="info"
                                                [provider] = "provider"></app-child-com>
```

This is my parent component.ts file

```
@ViewChild('FormFieldValues', {static: false}) formConfigValues: ChildComComponent;
setInfo(){
    this.service.getDetails().subscribe(res => {
     this.info = res;
    
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

I am trying access the pass data from child to parent component.

```
saveDetails(){
  console.log(this.formConfigValues.Id);
}
```

This is my child component.ts

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (this.info.length > 0 || this.info !== undefined) {    
      this.createForm();
    }
  }

private createForm() {
    const group = {};
    this.info.forEach(field => {
     if (field.type === 'text') {
        group[field.name] = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
        if (group[field.name] === 'id') {
          if (this.configFieldForm.get('id').value != null || this.configFieldForm.get('id').value != undefined) {
            this.Id = this.configFieldForm.get('id').value;
            console.log(this.Id);       
          }
        }
        if (group[field.name] === 'key') {
          if (this.configFieldForm.get('key').value != null || this.configFieldForm.get('key').value != undefined) {
            this.Key = this.configFieldForm.get('key').value;
            console.log(this.Key);
          }
        }
      }

    });
    this.configFieldForm = new FormGroup(group);
  }
```

This is my child component html file

```
<form [formGroup]="configFieldForm" >
  <div [isOpen]="isLiveOpen" [isDisabled]="isLiveDisabled" class="mb-3">    
    <ng-container *ngFor="let field of info">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <ng-template [ngIf]="field.type === 'heading'">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <h6>{{field.label}}</h6>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template [ngIf]="field.type === 'text'">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label class="col-form-label">{{field.label}}
                  <ng-template [ngIf]="field.required === true">
                    <span class="required-asterisk">*</span>
                  </ng-template>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="custom-file">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{field.label}}"
                    formControlName="{{field.name}}">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>              
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>
```

But I cannot access this value in parent conponent `console.log(this.formConfigValues.Id)` How toget the value user type in text box in child component and pass it to parent component. Currently It's coming as `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parentForm via @Input then assign the formGroup

In child components ngOnInit you can add `this.parentForm.addControl('childGroup', myGroup)`

Parent-child form combination playground:
[stackblitz playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ws73gc-ysyw7d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts)

Comment: I already build the form by passing parent data to child component. I want to again pass child component data to parent. I want to get `this.configFieldForm.get('key').value` & pass it to parent component

Comment: can you try this one : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ws73gc-ysyw7d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('Name:' + this.userForm.get('name').value);
console.log('Age:' + this.userForm.get('age').value);
console.log('City:' + this.userForm.get('city').value);
console.log('Country:' + this.userForm.get('country').value);
```